# My ex keeps coming to my house uninvited

Tags: trespass

A little under a year ago I broke up with my (ex) girlfriend because she cheated on me. I told her to get out of my life and I would stay out of hers and that was the end of it. Well for some reason this semester she keeps coming to my house uninvited and will not leave or stay away no matter how much I request it. Her response is always a long the lines of "you can't tell me what to do"

About the house:

- it's owned by the college we both attend
- there are 12 residents in the house, all of which say she has no reason to be here
- she has been over 3 times in the past 7 days
- she slept on the living room couch one night

I have tried telling her that she is on the black list we made and cannot enter the house.

How do I ensure that I can live peacefully in the privacy of my residence without her coming in whenever she pleases? We keep the doors locked but she either a) comes over with her friends who we are fine with or b) sneaks in when we have a lot of people over.

Is there something I can do legally to get the point across to her that she can not be here?

This is in the US

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the police and ask them to throw her out.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Just call 911 and say there is an unwanted guest that won't leave? Or would campus security be a better option?  Thanks for your answer

Comment: Some campus security departments actually are police departments staffed with full-fledged police officers. In that case it doesn't make a difference. On others they are just private security personnel who don't have any more authority than any other citizen. When it's the latter case, you might want to give the rent-a-cops a chance, but if they fail to remedy the situation, you might want to call the real police.

Answer (score 1):

You do not give a location.

If you are in Australia you can apply for (or have the police apply on your behalf) for an [Apprehended Violence Order](http://www.legalaid.nsw.gov.au/what-we-do/community-partnerships/womens-domestic-violence-court-advocacy-program/what-is-an-avo) (the link is for NSW but all states and territories have similar laws). This is an injunctive relief from the court which puts conditions on the person it is served on (e.g. to not come to your house). Breaching an AVO is a crime and the police can be called to arrest and lay charges.

Comment: I edited the post, does something like this exist in the United states?

Comment: It's a particular variant/hybrid of trespass notice. Surely that kind of notice or a locale-specific form of it will be available to you.

Comment: @user7686415 yes, it's usually called a Restraining Order in U.S. states.